What does Subcontinent surname Tarar mean and what is its origin?
I am from Pakistan and my last name is Tarar. It is a Jatt tribe from Punjab in both India and Pakistan. I’d like to know the meaning of this name and its origins. All I am aware of is that there was a person called Tarar whom this tribe was named after

Might you not get more help on WWW pages dealing with the meanings of names?
